# kohanim mikvah after bathroom

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, kohen-priest, chasidut-hasidism, bathroom

Rabbi Shlomo Calerbach says kohanim would go to the mikvah after going to the bathroom

And that Rav Yoel  the satmar Rebbe also did this

Looking for written sources for both of these ideas

https://youtu.be/yfqwkVQQXD4&t=1m58s

Comment: Are you thinking of the mishna Tamir 1:1?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.3.2?lang=he&with=all